# What to check before I allow upgrade from my system?

Tags: 11.04, upgrade

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 from last two months, I faced many problems while installing and stabilizing the OS *[first tried to normal dual boot, but had to install through wubi]*. It cost me three re-installations and loss of some data to stabilize my OS.

Currently the upgrade manager constantly shows that an upgrade to 11.04 is available for my system.

What should I check before I go ahead for upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas:

- **Live system:** I think the easiest way to check the stability of a new version of Ubuntu is to run it from a [live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) or a USB stick. Personally, I would recommend creating a persistent Ubuntu system on a USB stick using Startup Disk Creator. Boot the system, install any drivers, and test any applications you rely on.
- **No PPAs:** If you want a smooth upgrade, I would recommend against PPAs. If you have enabled some PPAs, uninstall its packages before upgrading your system.
- **Backups:** Another safe precaution is to make a backup. Backups are always a good idea anyway.